# show uniform convergence of $\ \ f_n(x)= \dfrac{1}{1+(x-n)^2}$ on any compact interval $[a,b] \in \mathbb R$.

Tags: real-analysis

show uniform convergence of $\ \ f_n(x)= \dfrac{1}{1+(x-n)^2}$  on any compact interval $[a,b] \subset \mathbb R$.

My attempt: I showed that the sequence of functions converges pointwise to $f=0$

Comment: I think your bound should be $\frac1{(n-M)^2}$

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** For $n\ge2|x|$,
$$
\frac1{1+(x-n)^2}\le\frac4{n^2}
$$

Answer (score 1):

Your idea is generaly correct, just change the $\frac{1}{M+n^2}$ into $\frac{1}{(M+n)^2}$ in the last limit. Also, perhaps a faster way of writing things would be this:
$$f_n(x) = \frac1{1+(x-n)^2} = \frac{1}{n^2}\frac{1}{\frac{1}{n^2} + \left(\frac{x}{n} - 1\right)^2}.$$ Now you can limit the second factor by limiting $x$, leaving you with $1/n^2$ which goes to $0$.

This is not a "better", just a slighlty different solution.

Answer (score 0):

If $n$ is large enough then $n > b$ and

$\displaystyle \sup_{x \in [a,b]} f_n = \frac{1}{1 + (b - n)^2} $

because in order to maximize $f_n$ you need to minimize $(x - n)^2$.